# Best Practice for Measures in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

Just wondering about best practices, and SPEED in asking this:

Does it matter if You Create a measure on a measure that is based on another measure,

or is it better to base that new Measure on the base Measure?

eg

```
BaseMeasure= Sum(x)

Measure1= Calculate(BaseMeasure,y=1 || y=2)
```

Should Measure2 be

```
(a) Calculate(Measure1, y=2)
```

OR

```
(b) Calculate(BaseMeasure,y=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

this is not valid DAX, but let's assume it's some pseudo-code

The main problem is that a and b measures would return different results

The (a) measure sets a filter context to y = 2, but then the Measure1 replaces this filter context with y = 1 || y = 2, and then evaluate the BaseMeasure with this filter. The result is precisely the same as if Measure1 was directly invoked.

The (b) measure instead sets the filter context to y = 2 and then invokes the BaseMeasure with this filter.

This can be simulated on dax.do with the following DAX code

```
DEFINE
    TABLE T =
        DATATABLE ( "Y", INTEGER, "X", INTEGER, { { 1, 10 }, { 2, 20 } } )
    MEASURE T[BaseMeasure] =
        SUM ( T[X] )
    MEASURE T[Measure1] =
        CALCULATE ( [BaseMeasure], T[Y] = 1 || T[Y] = 2 )
    MEASURE T[Measure2] =
        CALCULATE ( [Measure1], T[Y] = 2 )
    MEASURE T[Measure3] =
        CALCULATE ( [BaseMeasure], T[Y] = 2 )
EVALUATE
ROW ( "Measure2", [Measure2], "Measure3", [Measure3] )
```

that returns

[image: dax.do result]

here is the link to the [dax.do example](https://dax.do/YP1k831SdtY1SL/)

To answer the question about nesting measure call, when done correctly it's ok, but focusing mainly on the code architecture and readability.

From the performance point of view, it's hard to predict the performance just by looking ad the code (unless really bad), the right path for optimization is through testing.

Comment: Thank-you for the time you have taken to answer, but I still don't understand. I'm seeing this as set theory, and this doesn't make sense. Let's say y=1 to 3, where 1-apples, 2-pears, &  3 - oranges. So the Base measure contains the summation of Apples,Pears, and Oranges. Measure 1 then contains Apples and Pears. Surely querying Measure1 for Pears should equal the scenario of asking the Base measure for how many Pears, seeing as it that contains all 3 Fruits. It's SET Theory, and SQL, so why is the logic different in DAX?

Comment: DAX does't work this way. The filter expressions in CALCULATE replaces the existing filter context with a new one. To make the inner CALCULATE filter expression intersect the existing filter contest, then it's possible to use KEEPFILTER. DAX is different from any other existing programming language and even if I already knew many programming language I had to start from scratch by learning its peculiar concepts. I'd suggest to start from the free introductory course available on http://sqlbi.com